# Windows Batch - Getting Error when trying to send mail via blat.exe

Tags: windows, batch-file, blat

I have a simple batch-script, where at the end I want to send an automated e-mail by calling the function `blat.exe`:

```
blat.exe -body "Das ist ein Test von Admin" -s "ABCDEFGH" -attacht "\\server\C\applic\abcd\tool\output\datafile.txt" -f mail@adress.com -t mail@adress.com
```

I am getting the following error:

```
C:\C\applic\abcd\tool>blat.exe -body "Das ist ein Test von Admin" -s "ABCDEFGH" -attacht "\\server\C\applic\abcd\tool\output\datafile.txt" -f mail@adress.com -t mail@adress.com 
-body does not exist
```

I cannot figure out why it isn't working. Can anyone help here?

Comment: Wait, I looked on [blat syntax documentation](https://www.blat.net/syntax/syntax.html) where it is written for first argument `<filename>`: if your message body is on the command line, use a hyphen (-) as your first argument, and -body followed by your message. So your command line clearly misses one `-` between `blat.exe` and `-body`. It is always useful to carefully read the documentation of an application to use.

Comment: Follow @Mofi's hint about _a hyphen as your first argument_; take a look at [an example _Using Batch to call Blat_](https://www.blat.net/?faq/index.html#ex__using_batch_to_call_blat).